# Python Strip Isn't Removing Characters

Tags: python

I'm attempting to remove some unwanted characters from photo URLs.

The relevant code:

```
for img in imgSrc:
    print(img)
    img.strip('US40')
    print(img)
```

No errors thrown, but the output is the same from both print statements:

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51uUvUZNoUL._AC_US40_.jpg
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51uUvUZNoUL._AC_US40_.jpg
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51GQJaFyk1L._AC_US40_.jpg
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51GQJaFyk1L._AC_US40_.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strip only works on leading and trailing characters. You should use replace in this case

**Strip:**
S.strip([chars]) -> str

Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
whitespace removed.
If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.

**Replace:**
S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> str

Return a copy of S with all occurrences of substring
old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

```
for img in imgSrc:
    print(img)
    img = img.replace('US40',"")
    print(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.strip()` only removes characters from either end of the string. In this case, the text you want to remove is a few characters to the interior.

You can use `str.replace()` with an empty string to remove any occurrences of the character, *anywhere* in the string. Is this what you want?

```
print(img)
# https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51uUvUZNoUL._AC_US40_.jpg
img = img.replace('US40', '')
print(img)
# 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51uUvUZNoUL._AC__.jpg'
```

Comment: This code doesn't change variable my friend, You have to make an assignment

Comment: No problem mate :P

Answer (score 0):

Python strip is a function which returns a value which you must assign to a variable:

`x = text.strip()`

And as others stated in your case you **must** use something else for the job. So you have two issues at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use `img = img.replace("US40","")`

Answer (score 0):

Strip only deletes leading and trailing characters from a string. I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but if you're interested in deleting some part of the string throughout its full length then you can use string.replace() method and replace something to the empty string `""`.
For example, below code deletes all of the `a` characters from a string:

```py
s = 'abc12321cba'

print(s.replace('a', ''))
Output: bc12321cb
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1 - Using python string's **replace** function:

```
myString = myString.replace("US40","")
```

2- Using **re** (regex) library's **sub** (substitute) function.

```
import re
Mystring = re.sub("US40","",myString)
```